# Sort ArrayList<> Alphabetically in two parts depends if flag is marked

Tags: java, android, list, sorting, comparable

I have List of objects which has several several members the most important are fullName and isSubscribed. I want sort it alphabetically in the following order:

1. First show alphabetically ordered objects that isSubscribed flag true.
2. After that show also alphabetically sorted objects that isSubscribed flag is false.

example of expected Contacts order:

1. Barry (isSubscribed:true)
2. Ericsson (isSubscribed:true)
3. Andy (isSubscribed:false)
4. Cook (isSubscribed:false)

I call sort method of my list which has overridden method compareTo(). my code is alphabetically ordering properly for flag marked false, however flag marked true is just putting on top of that list without alphabetically order.
example of Contacts order that I have:

1. Ericsson (isSubscribed:true)
2. Barry (isSubscribed:true)
3. Andy (isSubscribed:false)
4. Cook (isSubscribed:false)

My overridden code of my Comparable Object (I cant use java 8 due to some circumstances(min sdk level), so please dont offer java8  solution):

```
   @Override
    public int compareTo(PersonalContact contact) {
        String fullName = getFullName() != null ? getFullName() : "";
        String contactFullName = contact.getFullName() != null ? contact.getFullName() : "";

         int c;
        PersonalContact c1 = this;
        PersonalContact c2 = contact;
        String fullNameContact1 = c1.getFullName();
        String fullNameContact2 = c2.getFullName();
        Boolean subscribedForPresenceContact1 = c1.isSubscribeForPresenceEnabled();
        Boolean subscribedForPresenceContact2 = c2.isSubscribeForPresenceEnabled();

        c = subscribedForPresenceContact1.compareTo(subscribedForPresenceContact2);

        if (subscribedForPresenceContact1) {
            return  -1;
        } else if (subscribedForPresenceContact2) {
            return 1;
        } else  if (fullName.equals(contactFullName)) {
            String id = getAndroidId() != null ? getAndroidId() : "";
            String contactId = contact.getAndroidId() != null ? contact.getAndroidId() : "";

            if (id.equals(contactId)) {
                List<ContactNumberOrAddress> noas1 = getNumbersOrAddresses();
                List<ContactNumberOrAddress> noas2 = contact.getNumbersOrAddresses();
                if (noas1.size() == noas2.size() && noas1.size() > 0) {
                    if (!noas1.containsAll(noas2) || !noas2.containsAll(noas1)) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < noas1.size(); i++) {
                            int compare = noas1.get(i).compareTo(noas2.get(i));
                            if (compare != 0) return compare;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    return Integer.compare(noas1.size(), noas2.size());
                }

                String org = getOrganization() != null ? getOrganization() : "";
                String contactOrg =
                        contact.getOrganization() != null ? contact.getOrganization() : "";
                return org.compareTo(contactOrg);
            }
            return id.compareTo(contactId);
        }
        return fullName.compareTo(contactFullName);
    }
```

Comment: Do you really mean at most java 7? (I ask as you mention **min** SDK.) With lambdas and comparing methods it would have been a one liner.

Comment: @JoopEggen, I mean Collection.stream and List.sort functions are required API level 24 while mine is 21, lambda can be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest just to use custom comparator for `Collections.sort`

Like

```
    class PersonalContactComparator implements Comparator<PersonalContact>
    {

        @Override
        public int compare(final PersonalContact o1, final PersonalContact o2)
        {
            if (o1.isSubscribeForPresenceEnabled() == o2.isSubscribeForPresenceEnabled()) {
                return o1.getFullName().compareTo(o2.getFullName());
            }

            if (o1.isSubscribeForPresenceEnabled()) {
                return 1;
            }

            return -1;
        }
    }
```

And use it as `Collections.sort(list, new PersonalContactComparator());`

PS: This approach is similar to another asnwers, but more general one

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you may use the following:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(pc -> pc.isSubscribeForPresenceEnabled() ? 0 : 1)
                    .thenComparing(PersonalContact::getFullName));
```

Or if I am not mistaken (I am not certain atm). Boolean being a Comparable:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(PersonalContac::isSubscribeForPresenceEnabled)
                    .reversed()
                    .thenComparing(PersonalContact::getFullName));
```

The ~comparing~ methods give a comparison key for any of LHS and RHS, which then can be compared.

Unfortunately there is no comparingBoolean.

Answer (score 0):

There probably a better way, but here my solution

```
 static void sort(final List<PersonalContact> contacts)
    {
        final List<PersonalContact> subscribed = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<PersonalContact> unsubscribed = new ArrayList<>();
        for(final PersonalContact contact : contacts)
        {
            if(contact.isSubscribeForPresenceEnabled())
                subscribed.add(contact);
            else
                unsubscribed.add(contact);
        }

        final PersonalContactComparator personalContactComparator = new PersonalContactComparator();
        subscribed.sort(personalContactComparator);
        unsubscribed.sort(personalContactComparator);

        contacts.clear();
        contacts.addAll(subscribed);
        contacts.addAll(unsubscribed);
    }

    private static class PersonalContactComparator implements Comparator<PersonalContact>
    {

        @Override
        public int compare(final PersonalContact o1, final PersonalContact o2)
        {
            return o1.getFullName().compareTo(o2.getFullName());
        }
    }
```